# How will I set if account_status = 1 then I can able to login otherwise not able to login?

Tags: mysql, sql, api, laravel-5, eloquent

How will I set if account_status = 1 then I can able to login otherwise not able to login? email, phone and password must be there. This is the following code

```
public function login(Request $request){ 

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password'),
        'account_status'=> request('account_status')])){ 
            $user = Auth::user(); 
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus); 
        } 
        else if(Auth::attempt(['phone' => request('phone'), 'password' => request('password'),
        'account_status'=> request('account_status')])){
            $user = Auth::user(); 
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus);
        }
        else{ 
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you try to match `account_status` to a value which you have got from the `request`, but you are actually in need to check whether it's 1, so change

```
'account_status'=> request('account_status')
```

to

```
'account_status'=> 1
```

both in your `if` and your `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct but I have never seen a way of accessing request variables as you have mentioned:

```
request('email')
```

Please use following format:

```
$request->input('email')
```

So your code should be:

```
public function login(Request $request){ 
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password'),
    'account_status'=> $request->input('account_status')])){ 
        $user = Auth::user(); 
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus); 
    } 
    else if(Auth::attempt(['phone' => $request->input('phone'), 'password' => $request->input('password'),
    'account_status'=> $request->input('account_status')])){
        $user = Auth::user(); 
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus);
    }
    else{ 
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
    } 
}
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Thanks, actually I want that if account_status is equal to 1 then only I can login. How will I set the condition